# API unsplash, не понимаю как правильно вставить код, что надо изменить

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Мне надо получить рандомную картинку с сервиса unsplash. Нашёл нужный метод, но не понимаю что с ним делать. Как я понял этот метод вернёт формат json, так а зачем мне этот формат, когда нужно как-то в   вставить картинку. Ещё не ясно что делает toJSON, в коде ругается. Надеюсь на вашу помощь. https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js#photo-random
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Запросы обычно выполняются в componentDidMount.
2. Полученный JSON нужно распарсить. В нем будут ссылки на картинки. нужные ссылки положить в this.state
3. Далее в методе render() в картинки в атрибут src вставить ссылки из стейта

Так же эта библиотека - unsplash-js нужна для server side rendering. Чем реакт не является по умолчанию

Comment: Спасибо, погуглю.